# PHP : reformat a date in

Tags: php, date, datetime

Good day,

I have the following date that I get from my imap_fetch_overview PHP function :

```
$overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox, $email_number, 0);

...

$date_event = $overview[0]->date;
```

This outputs a date like 'Fri, 30 Jun 2017 16:27:44 +0000 (UTC)'

In the meantime I have set my default timezone as following :

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Brussels');
```

What I would like now is to be able to retrieve my $date_event in a format dd.mm.yyyy HH:mm:ss (local time, in my case 30.06.2017 18:27:44).

I have therefore tried :

```
$date_event_formated = $date_event('dd.mm.YYYY HH:ii:ss');
```

When calling 'echo $date_event_formated;', the only thing I get is a Fatal error.

So sorry if the question might sound silly, but I don't really understand what I am doing wrong here? Before bothering you, I looked at the reference website http://php.net/manual/fr/function.date.php but I may have missed something.

Thanks very much for your time and appreciated help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtotime()` is able to handle the format that you have and convert it into timestamp. Then you can use it to format date in whatever format you want with `date()` function:

```
$date_event = 'Fri, 30 Jun 2017 16:27:44 +0000 (UTC)';
echo date('d.m.Y H:i:s',strtotime($date_event));
//outputs: 30.06.2017 18:27:44
```

Here's working example:

https://3v4l.org/obfNB

Answer (score 2):

While there is nothing wrong with Jakub's answer, using **php 5.3** and up you can also use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), using an exact mask to parse the incoming date-string.

```
$oldDate = 'Fri, 30 Jun 2017 16:27:44 +0000 (UTC)';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('D, d M Y H:i:s T e', $oldDate);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use strtotime:

$date_event = 'Fri, 30 Jun 2017 16:27:44 +0000 (UTC)';
echo date('d.m.Y H:i:s',strtotime($date_event));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Vishal